# mysql: export single row, but with all dependencies

Tags: sql, mysql, export

Mysql question.
I want to export one single row from one table with a catch: I want to pull together with it all the rows in all other tables referenced from the initial row by foreign keys - and referenced from the new rows too, recursively, until I get all rows that the initial one "needs to exist".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more inner joins until you make it through your data structure

```
Select * from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on
t1.pk = t2.fk
inner join table3 t3 on
t2.pk = t3.fk
.......
where t1.pk = {pk id number} limit 0,1
```

Comment: Any thoughts on making it look through the information_schema table to find all references? That way you don't have to manually specify or know which tables are referencing it?